# jQuery Validate: Change required message using select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been trying to change the message of the required rule for my form dynamically when the user changes the select option input. I can't seem to get anything to work properly. The message will never change after the selection is changed.

I try my methods using the change function for the select input like so:

```
$('#selector').change(function(){
     Method X;
}
```

Methods I've tried:

1. `$.validator.messages.required = "New Message";`
2. `$('#inputx').rules("remove", "required");`

   `$('#inputx').rules("add", { messages: {required: "New Message"}});`

I have also tried a depends function for the message, but that doesn't work at all:

```
required: {
    depends: function(element){
        if($('#selector option:selected').text() == 'Option1'){
            return "Message 1";
        } else{
            return "Message 2";
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The error message does not change even after unfocusing the #inputx element

EDIT: I did an incorrect conditional statement inside my onChange. Everything works perfectly now!

Comment: Where is your HTML markup?  Where is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.rules('add')` method is working fine for me...

http://jsfiddle.net/2NJS7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            test: {
                required: true
            },
            myselect: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

    $('select[name="myselect"]').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            $('input[name="test"]').rules('add', {
                messages: {
                    required: "this is the new message"
                }
            });
        } 
    });

});
```

Comment: Wow that worked! Thanks Sparky! Had so much trouble trying to wrap my head around what to do for this issue.

Comment: @Kronus, I'm glad it worked but since you didn't show your full code, I still have no idea where you went wrong.  Perhaps you can edit your OP to show your failed attempt so others might be helped when they read this.