# How to make a condition if option selected value with jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to do this way but it isn't working:

```
$('#contato').validate({
rules:{
    nome:       {required: true, notEqual: 'Nome'},
    email:      {required: true, notEqual: 'E-mail'},
    telefone:   {required: true},
    setor:      {required: true},
    if ($('#setor option:selected').val()=='trabalheConosco') {
        alert('worked')
    }
    mensagem:   {required: true, notEqual: 'Mensagem'}
}, ...
```

When I don't use the `if` condition, it works but when I do it doesn't.. does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: need one coma after if. Place If as the last one.

Comment: In order to properly answer the question, we'll need to know what you're trying to do with this this conditional.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is unclear.  What exactly do you want to do on this condition?  Change a rule?  Validate some other input?

You cannot just stick a chunk of JavaScript inside the `rules` option.  The `rules` option will only accept a comma separated list of `key: value` pairs and each `key` **must** be the `name` of a form input to be validated.

If you're trying to change a rule, you'd put the conditional inside of an external `change` event handler and use the `.rules()` method to add/change or remove the rule for any form input.

Here's a similar answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717771/594235

Answer (score -1):

In fact i missed the comma, but it didnt work too. I just put the if condition to the submitHandler and it worked

Comment: Keep in mind that the `submitHandler` only fires on a _valid_ form, which means that your conditional will do nothing until the form passes validation (when you click submit).